# Reachability issue on iPhone: networkStatusForFlags

Tags: iphone, ios, reachability

I'm doing a few server calls and getting back some json. The code is pretty simple, it does a call to sign you in, and then does another call to get more info. I keep getting Reachability errors when I try to make the second call.

```
Reachability Flag Status: -R ------- networkStatusForFlags
```

Not sure why it does that. I'm running this in the simulator and I'm on Wifi and the first call goes through just fine.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using the [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324) sample code from Apple, that is not an error but a debug message. In particular, the `R` flag means that the network is reachable (yay!).

The sample code prints reachability flags by default. You can turn off this behavior by setting `kShouldPrintReachabilityFlags` to 0 in [Reachability.m](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Classes_Reachability_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Classes_Reachability_m-DontLinkElementID_6):

```
#define kShouldPrintReachabilityFlags 0
```

Answer (score 0):

you can download the "Reachability" classes from the following URL and you can get the wifi and internet flag checking.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324

So, while requesting the API, you need to get the current status of internet connectivity of your device and if you are connected with that, request the API.

I think this may useful for you.

Comment: I suspect the OP is already using the Reachibility sample code.